# how to send an array of images with same keyword for multiple times?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

Here I need to send multiple images to the Postgres DB, for multiple times using Postman in single hit

For eg:

[image]
here I have taken `image` as a keyword two times, it saves every images name in each column in DB

Eg:
[image]
need first 2 images for first column and next 3 on next column and continues

code Stuff

model

```
  image: {
    data: Buffer,
    type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING),
    defaultValue: [],
    allowNull: false,
  },
```

dao

```
 if (!Array.isArray(variation)) {
      variation = [variation];
    }
    if (!Array.isArray(price)) {
      price = [price];
    }
    if (!Array.isArray(sales_price)) {
      sales_price = [sales_price];
    }
    if (!Array.isArray([filename])) {
      filename = [filename];
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < variation.length; i++) {
      await productDetails.create({
        variation: variation[i],
        price: price[i],
        sales_price: sales_price[i] || 0,
        image: [filename]
      });
    }
```

image

```
 uploads(req, res, async (err) => {
      if (!req.files || req.files == "") {
        const updated_response = setErrorResponseMsg(
          RESPONSE.PARAMETER_IS_MANDATORY,
          "Image"
        );
        return send(res, updated_response);
      } else if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
        return send(res, RESPONSE.FILE_SIZE);
      }
      if (err) {
        return send(res, RESPONSE.UNKNOWN_ERROR);
      }
      let filename = [];
      if (req.files != null) {
        req.files.forEach((ele) => {
          filename.push(ele.filename);
        });
      }
```